# Nav bar toggle not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I used toggle navbar as menu in my website for all devices. When I use this code it does not showing the 3 icon for collapsible nav bar. Please anyone find the errors in my code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="srch">
           <form method="post" class="col-md-7">
             <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="  SEARCH" id="srch">
           </form>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <a href="#top" class="navbar-brand"><img src="image/logo.jpg" width="250" height="74"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle x collapsed line" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-x">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You may try this bellow example according your requirement

```css
.navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;

  &:hover {
    background: transparent !important;
  }

  .icon-bar {
    width: 22px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .top-bar {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 10%;
  }
  .middle-bar {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .bottom-bar {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 90%;
  }

  &.collapsed {
    .top-bar {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
    .middle-bar {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .bottom-bar {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

for collapsible nav bar use this instead :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

change the screen size to see the effect.
https://jsfiddle.net/43rm9emw/

Comment: I saw this code in w3schools. but I don't want this type of navbar. Whta I need is, for every screen the menu Icon should be collapsible.when clicking the menu icon list should be inline and aligned in center of the browser window. Can you help me